# Is there a good way to make a wordcount macro in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, word-count

I have used this command to count words in LaTeX, but it has some weaknesses:

- Although it is supposed to surpress error messages, it does not always do this (see picture).
- It cannot count words produces by `\lipsum` command (and similar commands). If I have a macro `\producetext` which is defined by `\newcommand{\producetext}{This command produces a string of 8 words.}`, this is not included in the word count.

```
    \newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
      \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -merge -sum -q #1.tex > #1-words.sum}%
       \input{#1-words.sum}%
    }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% The command:
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -merge -sum -q #1.tex > #1-words.sum}%
   \input{#1-words.sum}%
}

\newcommand{\producetext}{This command produces a string of 8 words.}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{body.tex}

Hello, here is some other text from another file that we have 
included. This produces an error...

\end{filecontents}

\title{This is a Test}
\author{vebjornzen}
\date{January, 2023}


\begin{document}

%TC:ignore
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    Words: \quickwordcount{word-counter}
\end{center}
%TC:endignore

% This is not included in the word count:
\producetext
\lipsum[1]

% This produces "(errors:1)":
\input{body.tex}
\include{body.tex}


\end{document}
```

Here is some documentation:

---

https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F

What I want is for the macro to count the words displayed in the (final) PDF. I also do not want to get error messages when I try to print the word count. Is there some way to achieve this? I do not mind trying a different approach.

Comment: I suspect this would be really difficult. Probably the best path is to use the pdf, convert to text and count words there.

Comment: `texcount` may be helpful... https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/download.html

Answer (score 0):

The *I know best* type of answer would be that you should figure out what causes the error and fix it. The main reason for this is that the error message indicates that there is something TeXcount couldn't interpret, and while it might be insignificant, it could also be an indication of a major issue for TeXcount which results in an unreliable word count. Note that TeXcount does not actually do the typesetting, but relies on heuristic rules for interpreting macros, which are not always accurate, and so it may have problems even on perfectly valid documents.

A central feature of TeXcount is that it can produce detailed output indicating how each element of the document is interpreted. You may run this online on the [TeXcount web service](https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php): just cut-and-paste the segments or files you suspect contain the problem, and see how it is counted.

However, to answer your actual question, there is a solution which completely suppresses errors from the summary output. Just include the following code in the main TeX-file:

```
%TC:newtemplate
%TC:template {sum}
```

The templates can be used to specify custom output formats, as opposed to the hard-coded output formats.

You will still need the `-sum -merge` options to generate to total count and merge the files, and remove the `-1` option which would override the template format. Not sure if the `-q` option will make a difference.